# FFMPEG - merge (NOT concatenate) multiple sets of 2 videos in for loop

Tags: macos, ffmpeg, video, shell-script

I have a folder A with mp4 audio.
Folder B has mp4 video.
The filenames match, expect that they are in different folders.

These are movie files that when they were downloaded came in two separate files. Now I want to merge them back together using FFMPEG.

I have a very long list of 100+ files so I'm trying to automate the process.

I have tried many different combinations of the code below:
This code below didn't work, gave me an error and didn't run the process:

```
  audiopath="/Audio"

for i in /Video/*.mp4
do
    if ! [[ -e "$ audiopath /${i##*/}" ]]
    then
>&2 echo "no matching file in $ audiopath for $i"
        continue
    fi
    out="${i##*/}"
    out="/Movies/${out%.*}-$(%title)"

    ffmpeg -i <(printf '%s\n' "file '$i'") -i ("file '$ audiopath /${i##*/}'") -c:v copy -c:a copy "$out.mp4"
done
```

If I use swap the below and use it with code 1 above it concatenates the files one after the others but I get no sound, just a long video.

```
  ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i <(printf '%s\n' "file '$i'" "inpoint 0" "file '$seconddirectory/${i##*/}'" "inpoint 0") -c copy "$out.mp4"
```

This second code works, but of course has to be done manually:

```
 ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i audio.mp4 -c:v copy -c:a copy OUTPUT_FILE.mp4
```

After many hours, I've come here for help.
Does anyone know how to fix this code or can point me to the right direction?

Comment: What script language are you using are you on Windows?

Comment: The script should check if for each video there is a matching audio file and if yes merge them in a third output folder?